# Microsoft Graph API UnableToDeserializePostBody 400 error

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to create recurring events under my outlook calendar and for that, I'm following instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-schedule-recurring-events).

My payload looks like this:

```
{
  "Subject": "Blocked By DEV",
  "Body": {},
  "Start": {
      "DateTime": "2022-08-30T23:30:00",
      "TimeZone": "Asia/Calcutta"
  },
  "End": {
      "DateTime": "2022-08-30T23:45:00",
      "TimeZone": "Asia/Calcutta"
  },
  "Recurrence": {
      "pattern": {
          "type": "WEEKLY",
          "interval": 1,
          "daysOfWeek": [
              "Monday",
              "Tuesday"
          ]
      },
      "range": {
          "type": "numbered",
          "startDate": "2022-08-30",
          "numberOfOccurences": 3
      }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to hit the endpoint `/me/events` from [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and getting this 400 error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnableToDeserializePostBody",
        "message": "were unable to deserialize "
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my payload? Is there any way to have more details about the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spotted the culprit, `numberOfOccurences` was supposed to be `numberOfOccurrences`.

And if someone asks why I ended up doing that mistake, I just referred docs, and seems like [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-schedule-recurring-events#relevant-properties-6) has that typo.

Comment: Update: I added a PR for this, and the typo is fixed now.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/18237